# Como retornar ao estado anterior? (Vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estou utilizando o Vuex para gerenciar os estados do meu app e estou criando um botão avancar e um voltar, no caso do meu avançar eu utilizo a função abaixo:

```
addUser() {
      const payload = {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email
      };
      this.$store.commit("CHANGE_USER", payload);
    }
```

Porém fiquei na dúvida no botão voltar, eu devo dar um commit em uma variável vazia? É possível voltar a um "estado anterior"? Essa é a maneira correta?

Comment: Você pode tentar armazenar o valor atual do usuário no componente, se clicar em avanaçar você faz commit dele para a store e se ele voltar você não faz nada e deixa o valor que já estava na store. Funciona pra você?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi corretamente você pode ter dois "commites" para cada caso. Um *gravando* o `current_user` e o outro gravando o `last_user` por exemplo.

Ai fica a cargo das ações de cada botão saber qual *state* eles devem olhar.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor solução seria criar um outro estado(Array[]) para armazenar as mudanças no usuário.

E na mutation CHANGE_USER, você faria .push nesse estado com o estado atual do usuário, somente após isso você atualizaria o objeto do usuário.

E aí na outra mutation de recuperar o usuário você só atualizaria o objeto do usuário chamando .pop no Array com o histórico de mudanças, por que assim você removeria o último item e retornaria ele para o seu estado.